# Window Soft Input Mode ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

Earlier there was no problem with soft input mode, but after including `ConstraintLayout`, content of fragment doesn't move up when the keyboard appears.

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.pinspb.pinsupport">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="ru.pinspb.pinsupport.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ru.pinspb.pinsupport.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:name=".PinApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".auth.ui.HomeActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".front.ui.FrontActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".chats.ui.InitChatActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Fragment

```
public class AuthFragment extends Fragment implements ValidationListener {

    private static final String TAG = AuthFragment.class.toString();
    // UI references.
    @NotEmpty @Email @BindView(R.id.email) EditText email;
    @NotEmpty @BindView(R.id.password) EditText password;
    @BindView(R.id.auth_sign_in) Button signIn;
    @BindView(R.id.remember_me) CheckBox remember;
    @BindView(R.id.forgot) TextView forgot;
    @BindView(R.id.error) TextView errorField;
    @Inject @ApplicationContext
    Context context;
    private Validator validator;
    private onAuthenticateEventListener authenticatableEventListener;
    private String error = Constants.EMPTY_STRING;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            authenticatableEventListener = (onAuthenticateEventListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View render = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auth, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, render);

        final View activityRootView = render.findViewById(R.id.activity_root);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
            int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
            if (heightDiff > Helper.dpToPx(container.getContext(), 200)) { // if more than 200 dp, it's probably a keyboard...
                Log.d(TAG, "heightDiff: " + heightDiff);
            }
        });

        return render;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        errorField.setText(this.error);

        if(this.error.equals(Constants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
            errorField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            errorField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Set up the login form.
        password.setOnEditorActionListener((textView, id, keyEvent) -> {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        validator = new Validator(this);
        validator.setValidationListener(this);

        signIn.setOnClickListener(v -> validator.validate());
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    private void attemptLogin() {

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = this.email.getText().toString();
        String password = this.password.getText().toString();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("email", email);
        bundle.putString("password", password);

        authenticatableEventListener.sendAuthRequest(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidationSucceeded() {
        attemptLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
        for (ValidationError error : errors) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onValidationFailed: " + error.getCollatedErrorMessage(context));
            View view = error.getView();
            String message = error.getCollatedErrorMessage(context);

            // Display error messages ;)
            if (view instanceof EditText) {
                ((EditText) view).setError(message);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setErrors(String text) {
        this.error = text;
    }

    public interface onAuthenticateEventListener {
        void sendAuthRequest(Bundle params);
        void showErrors(String error);
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:id="@+id/activity_root">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_root"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_root"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_root"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activity_root"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_pin_support"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDiscription"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_root"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_root"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_root"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/auth.email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/auth.sizes"
        android:autoLink="none"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_root"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/error"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_root"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.56" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/auth.password"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/auth.sizes"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/auth.title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:textColor="@color/greyish_brown"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_root"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_root"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:text="@string/auth.remember"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/remember_me"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/auth.sizes"
        android:textColor="@color/warm_grey"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_root"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_root"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/auth.submit"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:id="@+id/auth_sign_in"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/auth.sizes"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_root"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/remember_me"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_root"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/auth.forgot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forgot"
        android:textColor="@color/pinkish_grey"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/auth_sign_in"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/auth_sign_in"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/auth_sign_in" />

    <TextView
        android:text="error"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/error"
        android:textColor="@color/lipstick"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the pic for understanding:

[image]

How can I understand what is going on? I've used ViewTreeObserver before.

**U.P.D.**

My goal is

[image]

I expected content to move up when keyboard appears, but keyboard is overlapping it instead.

Comment: there are number of bugs in ConstrainLayout. So, try to open issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?q=label:Component-Support-Libraries

Comment: Can you state clearly what's the behaviour you've expected? Did you expect the content to be scrollable?

Comment: @MarcinKoziński, yes, of course, view upd upper please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Everything actually works as intended with the way your layout is built -- margins are fixed distances, so your UI is simply too tall for the smaller screen. You would need to modify your layout to better adapt for a small layout -- either marking unnecessary views (e.g. the logo) as gone (ConstraintLayout will consider "gone" views as collapsed to a single point, in essence -- so the layout still works), or change some margins dimensions to a smaller value.

The usual way to build this is to use [bias constraints](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/constraintlayout-part-4/) or [guidelines](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/constraintlayout-part-6/), instead of hard margins. Using bias or guidelines (in percent mode) would allow you to have more of a "spring"-like behaviour to react better to dimension changes. Typically a layout will be a mix of hard margins and bias / guidelines.

To sum up, your options are:

- change the layout to use bias / guidelines (percent) constraints to have a more responsive layout
- mark some views as `GONE` when detecting the keyboard
- change some other values on the fly (font size, margin values...)
- or, create another layout file for handling this case

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you be a bit more specific on using guidelines to be responsive to the soft keyboard showing? Is the soft keyboard always a percentage height of the screen so one should have a guideline for that much?

Comment: Providing xml example would help much better

Comment: There isn't a native keyboard listener you can use to hide the views.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure in what Activity your fragment is located but if it's in for example InitChatActivity, just add adjustResize to your manifest, and wrap your ConstraintLayout in ScrollView or NestedScrollView:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Comment: It worked when I wrapped it with ScrollView and added the code in the manifest. Thank you. @r1m

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem with you, we declared `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but in fact the App showed the results like `adjustPan`, the contents are gone on top of the soft keyboard. So I set `adjustResize` programmatically, successfully solved this problem:

Just add this line to your `onCreate`:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score 1):

***work for me (in view)***:

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

android:focusableInTouchMode="true"