# Chinese Keyboard hides EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

When I try to fill in something in an EditText which is at the bottom of the screen, the Chinese keyboard hides the EditText. 
How should I resolve this problem? 
Below is my xml code and pictures.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
     <ScrollView>
         <LinearLayout>
             <EditText>
                 android:hint="Write down your opinion"
             </EditText>
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

following is my pics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9neC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc1Dw.png)

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"  should do the trick i believe

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I had tried it before, it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323537/window-soft-input-mode-constraintlayout seems to be related to the constraintsLayout, check out this thread

Answer (score 0):

- Remove your constraint layout

> From this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
              <EditText>

              </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> To this

```
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
              <EditText>

              </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how if there are still other code within <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout> like below 
    `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ApprovalTodoContentActivity"
    android:background="#585A56">`